# Unable to export RDS snapshot to S3: "This operation is not currently supported"

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-rds

I am trying to export MySQL RDS to S3 following [Exporting DB Snapshot Data to Amazon S3 - Amazon Relational Database Service](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_ExportSnapshot.html).

There are two issues:

- When I am using the steps in AWS console, I am not able to see the "For Actions, choose Export to Amazon S3" option.
- If I use the AWS CLI,

```
    aws rds start-export-task --export-task-identifier my_snapshot_export \
    --source-arn arn:aws:rds:AWS_Region:123456789012:snapshot:snapshot_name \
    --s3-bucket-name my_export_bucket \
    --iam-role-arn iam_role \
    --kms-key-id master_key
```

it gives the following error:

> An error occurred (InvalidParameterCombination) when calling the StartExportTask operation: This operation is not currently supported.

[image: snapshot-action]

[image: Aurora MySQL - version]

Comment: Which region are you using? The [Announcing Amazon Relational Database Service (RDS) Snapshot Export to S3](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2020/01/announcing-amazon-relational-database-service-snapshot-export-to-s3/) page says: "now available in US East (N. Virginia), US East (Ohio), US West (Oregon), Europe (Ireland), and Asia Pacific (Tokyo) Regions".

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Are you sure you are in the [right region](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_ExportSnapshot.html#USER_ExportSnapshot.Overview)?

Exporting snapshots is supported in the following AWS Regions:

- US East (N. Virginia)
- US East (Ohio)
- US West (Oregon)
- Europe (Ireland)
- Asia Pacific (Tokyo)

#### Note

You can copy a snapshot from an AWS Region where S3 export isn't supported to one where it is supported, then export the copy. The S3 bucket must be in the same AWS Region as the copy.

Comment: Thanks, this was confusing me a bit as well. This should be marked as the correct answer.

Comment: The docs should be updated, as it says "Amazon RDS supports exporting snapshots in all AWS Regions except the followin" then two "GovCloud" ones.

Comment: I'm getting the following error: "An error occurred (InvalidParameterValue) when calling the StartExportTask operation: DbEngine not supported" is there a list of engines supported? I'm using Oracle.

Comment: This information is now out of date and export is supported much broader: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/Concepts.RDS_Fea_Regions_DB-eng.Feature.ExportSnapshotToS3.html